# Error when using Jax to generate Proxy web service client

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I was wondering if i could get some help with the following issue.

I was trying to run the command below using jax to generate web service client  proxy:

```
wsimport http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/HolidayService.asmx?WSDL
```

but i'm getting the following error:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Asher>wsimport http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/HolidayService.asmx?WSDL
parsing WSDL...


[WARNING] src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 's:schema'. It was detected that 's:schema' is in namespace 'http:/
/www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'http://www.h
olidaywebservice.com/Holidays/HolidayService.asmx?WSDL#types?schema1'. If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the p
refix of 's:schema' needs to be changed. If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be ad
ded to 'http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/HolidayService.asmx?WSDL#types?schema1'.
  line 15 of http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/HolidayService.asmx?WSDL#types?schema1

[ERROR] undefined element declaration 's:schema'
  line 15 of http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/HolidayService.asmx?WSDL

[ERROR] undefined element declaration 's:schema'
  line 36 of http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/HolidayService.asmx?WSDL

[ERROR] undefined element declaration 's:schema'
  line 74 of http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/HolidayService.asmx?WSDL

[ERROR] undefined element declaration 's:schema'
  line 97 of http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/HolidayService.asmx?WSDL

[ERROR] undefined element declaration 's:schema'
  line 120 of http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/HolidayService.asmx?WSDL

[ERROR] undefined element declaration 's:schema'
  line 131 of http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/HolidayService.asmx?WSDL


C:\Users\Asher>
```

First of all am i doing something incorrectly? And lastly if there's no way to generate a proxy client then is there any other way to access this webservice & it's methods in java.
I'm fairy new to java so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How did you create that WSDL? It seams that you refer some data types that are not exported in your WSDL.

**EDIT**

The wsdl refers to a schema named 's' but this can't be found, because its URL is

http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema but should be

http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema**.xsd**

after change that now it also complains about http://www.27seconds.com/Holidays/ that isn't pointing to a schema too. You need to fix all of them in your copy of the WSDL and then do the wsimport with it.

I also gone to www.holidaywebservice.com and found there's a second version at:
http://www.holidaywebservice.com/HolidayService_v2/HolidayService2.asmx?wsdl

Comment: I didn't create the wsdl so sadly i have no control over it.

Answer (score 11):

You can pass XMLschema as parameter on wsimport

```
wsimport -b  http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd  http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/HolidayService.asmx?WSDL
```

There are potential name conflicts in schema for schema.
A workaround is to create **customization.xjb** with following

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" version="2.0">
<globalBindings>
<xjc:simple/>
</globalBindings>
<bindings scd="~xsd:complexType">
<class name="ComplexTypeType"/>
</bindings>
<bindings scd="~xsd:simpleType">
<class name="SimpleTypeType"/>
</bindings>
<bindings scd="~xsd:group">
<class name="GroupType"/>
</bindings>
<bindings scd="~xsd:attributeGroup">
<class name="AttributeGroupType"/>
</bindings>
<bindings scd="~xsd:element">
<class name="ElementType"/>
</bindings>
<bindings scd="~xsd:attribute">
<class name="attributeType"/>
</bindings>
</bindings>
```

your ultimate call would be

```
wsimport -b  http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd -b customization.xjb  http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/HolidayService.asmx?WSDL
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip using the XMLSchema.xsd as a parameter for wsimport, I have forgotten this and it solves my today problem :)