# Referenced type can not be found while trying to import WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, mule, wsimport

I'm trying to generate a Java Service Class in Mule from this WSDL using the SOAP component's Import WSDL and generate JAX-WS classes feature: https://www.tracegains.net/api/scsi.asmx?WSDL

[image: Generate from WSDL Dialog]

But I'm getting an `undefined element declaration 's:schema' at line xx column yy of schema` (error repeated quite a few times).

[image: XML Schema Error]

So, based on this answer: [Error when using Jax to generate Proxy web service client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209583/error-when-using-jax-to-generate-proxy-web-service-client) I saved the WSDL file locally and changed the reference from http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema to http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd

Now I'm getting a `Part <parameters> in Message <{http://www.tracegains.net/Services}GetAttributesByIngredientSoapOut> referenced Type <{http://www.tracegains.net/Services}GetAttributesByIngredientResponse> can not be found in the schemas.`

[image: referenced Type can not be found in the schemas]

I also tried the wsimport tool from Apache CXF 3.0.0 but I'm getting similar results there:

```
[ERROR] Schema descriptor {http://www.tracegains.net/Services}Version in message part "parameters" is not defined and could not be bound to Java. Perhaps the schema descriptor {http://www.tracegains.net/Services}Version is not defined in the schema imported/included in the WSDL. You can either add such imports/includes or run wsimport and provide the schema location using -b switch.  line 774 of file:/D:/tg/tg_modified.wsdl
```

It appears to me that the import is failing on the tns namespace, but when I try to browse the tns namespace uri I'm getting a 404: http://www.tracegains.net/Services  Is this the problem or is there something else I can do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

More possibly, the schema containing the definition of `parameters` is missing and not imported during generation of stub and model classes. The solution is to save the WSDL and related XSD schema files in local and import the schema with correct location and retry doing it

Comment: I looked through all the schema files referenced and could not find any that defined "parameters".  Could it be that this is defined in http://www.tracegains.net/Services that I can't import because I'm getting a file not found error?  Thanks.